# Xamarin iOS move UIButton with it click area

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a UIButton in View and use UITapGestureRecognizer for this button.
 I have a problem with button moving: when i click it i want to change button Y coordinate (raise or lower button).

I try to do this after button click:

```
View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, topOffset, 320, 40);
```

or

```
View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, 320, 40 + _topOffset );  
_button.Frame = new RectangleF (80, _topOffset, 160, 40);
```

The UI moves good, but click the area remains in the same place or stretched down.
I want that click area was limited perimeter buttons

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a UITapGestureRecognizer for the UIButton, why not just use the available button click events:

```
myButton.TouchUpInside += HandleButtonTouchUpInside;

void HandleButtonTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
myButton.Frame = new RectangleF(myButton.Frame.X, myButton.Frame.Y + _topOffset, myButton.Frame.Width, myButton.Frame.Height);

}
```

If you want to animate the change, just wrap it like this:

```
UIView.Animate (0.5f, delegate {
    // put the frame change in here
});
```

And an even better solution would be use AutoLayout constraints on the button and just update them in the HandleButtonTouchUpInside method, with some animation.

And remember to unhook the event handler in ViewWillDisappear:

```
myButton.TouchUpInside -= HandleButtonTouchUpInside;
```